Find the greatest value of the function $y=2.3^{3x−3^{2x}}.4+2.3^x$ in the interval $[−1,1]$
The greatest value of the function $y=2.3^{3x-3^{2x}}.4+2.3^x$ in the interval $[-1,1]$ is
My approach is as follow
$y=2.3^{3x-3^{2x}}.4+2.3^x$
$y=8.3^{3x-3^{2x}}+2.3^x$
$y'=8.3^{3x-3^{2x}}.(3-2.3^{2x})+2.3^x=0$
How do we find the value of $x$ for which $y'=0$

The derivative is wrong, those are not powers of $e.$

Log base 3 is deleted

@Moo cross checked it problem is written correctly from the source

https://studylib.net/doc/26263527/aits-2021-ft-vii-jeea-paper-1

Question 50 represent the question

This question is odd, the quizz asks only for a numerical value which graphically is $f(1)$ and you would have correct answer without justification. However proving the local maxima at $x\approx 0.275$ is smaller than $f(1)$ seems really hard.

Do you mean $y=2 \cdot 3^{3x−3^{2x}} \cdot 4+2 \cdot 3^x$ or do you mean $2.3$ as in $\frac{23}{10}$?

They are using the dot as multiply in question 54 as well in the pdf linked, so probably a multiplication.

You don't have to find the greatest value of the function using the derivative.
You can say that the function is monotonic increasing, thus, the maximum value is at $f(1)$.

@Chessplayer - You cannot say the function is increasing without providing some argument that this is the case. According to zwim (I haven't checked myself), it isn't.

@PaulSinclair
Yes, the problem is that he wrote the function not in the "usual way". I thought he meant the function:
$$f(x)=8.3^{3x-3^{2x}}+2.3^x$$
